# Database design for django application

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have a problem to make it easier : I have a relation like   `user -> Hotel - >  Rooms`  . User can create Hotel and then every hotel can have many rooms .

Now I have a user model like

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    company_number=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
```

and to create restaurant

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    rest_owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rest_owner')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=30)
```

and now room

```
class Room(models.Model):
    rest_owner = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rest_owner')
    name = models.IntegerField()
    Rooms = models.IntegerField()
```

is that a good approach to do this ? and to save images of room and restaurant Should I make a

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, upload_to='Gallery')
```

and then use in room and restaurant like     `images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)`  ? . I need to know best ways to doing both of these . thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your design is fine, however, there are a few minor issues:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    company_number=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
```

1. the User model already has an email field, so you don't need one here.
2. `null=False, blank=False` is the default and should be dropped.
3. if `company_name` and `company_number` are related then you should make this 2nd Normal Form by making them a foreign key to a `Company` model

```
    class Company(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        number = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

For the `Restaurant` model:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    rest_owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, 
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                   related_name='rest_owner')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=30)
```

1. The `rest_owner` foreign key says that one user can own multiple `Restaurants`, and
   the `on_delete=CASCADE` says that if you delete a `User` or `UserProfile`, then then 
   all associated `Restaurants` should also be deleted. Are you sure this is what you 
   want?
2. The `related_name` makes it so you can say `my_user.rest_owner.all()` to get all the restaurants owned by the user, which doesn't exactly flow of the tongue. It's better to use a plural of the class name you're in, i.e. `related_name="restaurants"` will give you `my_user.restaurants.all()`.
3. It doesn't make sense to have `TextFields` with a length less than the max length for a `CharField`.
4. I would make country a two character field and fill it with the country's ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code.

For the `Room` model:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    rest_owner = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, 
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                   related_name='rest_owner')
    name = models.IntegerField()
    Rooms = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the `name` and `Rooms` fields, so I'll skip those. For the foreign key to `Restaurant`:

1. It is a good practice to name the foreign key field with the name of the model it points to, i.e.

```
    class Room(models.Model):
        restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, ...)
```

that allows you to say e.g.: `my_room.restaurant.city`.

2. similarly to above, the related name should be a plural of the model you're in, so

```
    class Room(models.Model):
        restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name='rooms', ...)
```

which gives you `my_restaurant.rooms.all()`, which is reads much better than `my_restaurant.rest_owner.all()` -- which would be hard to guess returned rooms...

For the images you need to consider:

1. can images be shared between rooms (yes => ManyToMany, no => ForeignKey)
2. if an image is edited, should all the rooms that use the image get the changes immediately (yes => ManyToMany, no => ForeignKey).

a good rule-of-thumb though is - if you're in doubt, probably use a foreign key ;-)

Comment: perfect explanation . Just one question , if I want to have multiple image against every room I should use ManyToMany  image field I think ?

Comment: Yes, if the same set of images should be used with more than one room it would be sensible to use a ManyToMany field.